# Specify in Scrapy which file to export data into depending on scraped results

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I create a set of files when I launch my scrapy spider like so:

```
year1.csv
year2.csv
year3.csv
```

Also clear the file if it exists and has content inside of it.

And during parse, export to each file according to scrapy results like so:

```
def parse(self,response):
 if response.css('#Contact1'):
  yield{
   'Name': response.css('#ContactName1 a::text').extract_first()
  }

 if response.css('#Contact1').extract_first() is "1":
  export to year1.csv
 if response.css('#Contact1').extract_first() is "2":
  export to year2.csv
 if response.css('#Contact1').extract_first() is "2":
  export to year3.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pipeline to do this. here is the official documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

here is how i would go about doing it.
I would create a different item for different documents

item.py

```
class Year1Item():
    name = scrapy.field()
class Year2Item():
    name = scrapy.field()
class Year3Item():
    name = scrapy.field()
```

then in your spider file you could do this

```
def parse(self,response):
  if response.css('#Contact1'):
    if response.css('#Contact1').extract_first() is "1":
        item = Year1Item()
    if response.css('#Contact1').extract_first() is "2":
        item = Year2Item()
    if response.css('#Contact1').extract_first() is "2":
        item = Year3Item()
    item['Name'] = response.css('#ContactName1 a::text').extract_first()
    return item
```

then in your pipeline.py file

```
 def process_item(self, item, spider):
     if isinstance(item,Year1Item):
         export to year1.csv
     if isinstance(item,Year2Item):
         export to year2.csv
     if isinstance(item,Year3Item):
         export to year3.csv
```

inside your pipeline file you can have a function that runs when your spider opens

```
def open_spider(self,spider):
    #maybe here you could use python to check if the files already exist and delete them if they do
```